# Trying gather data with django-dynamic-scraper (django, scrapy)

Tags: python, django, xpath, scrapy, django-dynamic-scraper

I am using django-dynamic-scraper in one of my applications, I have gone through the docs and following is my setup:
[image]
[image]
1)Unfortunately, the scraper works only with first page and gathers well only url_proiect and question, on the other side, other attributes remain empty. I tried to paste both relative and absolute XPath for these objects, but nothing worked.

2)I don't understand well how should I set Detail Pages for SCRAPER ELEMENTS and REQUEST PAGE TYPES.

What is the best way to debug a scraper in such a case? How can I find the correct XPath with minimal number of tryings?

Comment: As for finding the correct XPath, getting a browser extension such as Firefox's XPath Checker can help alot.

Comment: I tried, but it seems that the XPath is still wrong or my setting are. I try to understand where is the problem.